# How to get new Client Secret once the old one expires in Azure App?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-authentication, azure-rest-api

My **Azure App's** `client secret` expiry was set to 3 months which has expired and the application has stopped. My questions are:

1. How can I get the new client secret to the same **Azure App** to
   replace the new `client secret` in my **NodeJS** application?
2. Also is there a way to get a warning or message/mail before the `client secret` expire?
3. How to check the expiry of `client credentials` without using the Azure portal( that is by using **REST requests** if any)?

*Screen Shot showing expiry in Azure portal. Can we get this expiry somehow by REST requests?*
[image]

Comment: `How can I get the new client secret to the same Azure App to replace the new client secret in my NodeJS application?` - How are you currently setting the client secret?

Comment: I am getting them through the Certificates and Secrets section in the manage App tab. Can I create multiple secret keys for the same app? and once the old one expires do I have to create a new client secret and update that in my nodeJS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 3. How to check the expiry of client credentials without using the Azure
>    portal( that is by using REST requests if any)?

You should be able to use `Graph API` to get this information. The operation you would want to invoke is [`List applications`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which will give you a list of `application` objects. The [`property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) you would want to check is [`passwordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordcredential?view=graph-rest-1.0) for credential expiry.

> 2. Also is there a way to get a warning or message/mail before the client secret expire?

AFAIK, there is not an automated way to do this. I believe I read somewhere that Graph API team is working on it but there was no ETA provided for this by them. For now you have to roll out your own solution. You may write a timer-triggered Azure Function which runs daily. This Function can get the list of applications and filter out the applications credentials for which are expiring soon and take action on that.

> 1. How can I get the new client secret to the same Azure App to replace the new client secret in my NodeJS application?

Based on your comment, considering you are currently doing this process manually so I would assume you can continue to do so. Once you know that the secret is expiring soon, you can create a new application secret and at appropriate time replace the old secret with the new secret.